# Laravel call a model class using a variable as its name

Tags: class, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have just started using Laravel queues and don't know if this can't be done in Laravel

Instead of doing this which works...

```
$test1 = Test1::where('fieldname', $value)->exists();
$test2 = Test2::where('fieldname', $value)->exists();
$test3 = Test3::where('fieldname', $value)->exists();
$test4 = Test4::where('fieldname', $value)->exists();
```

I want to create an array of model classes and fieldnames then loop over the array...

```
$classes = [
    'Test1' => 'fieldname',
    'Test2' => 'fieldname',
    'Test3' => 'fieldname',
    'Test4' => 'fieldname',
];

foreach($classes as $class => $field) {
    $class::where($field, $groupid)->exists();
}
```

but when I run my job I get the following message and it dies

> Class 'Test1' not found

I want to do other stuff inside the loop which reduces my code down a lot and looks more readable.

Can you not call a class using a variable like I tried?

Here is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use \App\Models\Test;

class ImportProductGroupCrm implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $product;
    public $tries = 1;

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $classes = [
            'Test' => 'field-Name',
        ];

        foreach($classes as $class => $field) {
            $class::where($field, $groupid)->exists();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the whole class name or use `::class`:

```php
$classes = [
    'App\Test1' => 'fieldname',
    Test1::class => 'fieldname',
];
```